# What is mean 's' in end of names of controllers and views of Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I studding to developing component for Joomla 2.5 by this totorial:

```
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component
```

Now, there is several cases such as:

```
HelloWorldControllerHelloWorld
HelloWorldControllerHelloWorlds
```

in files:

```
controllers/helloworld.php
controllers/helloworlds.php
```

or:

```
HelloWorldControllerHelloWorld
HelloWorldControllerHelloWorlds
```

in files:

```
helloworld/view.html.php
helloworlds/view.html.php
```

My question is:
What the difference between those cases when there is 's' in end and cases when you don't have 's' in the end?

And second thing.
This totorial is very good, but it is good as totorial. Is some one have some site whith deep documentation of all these concepts (exept Joomla API)?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The "s" at the end of the class declaration denotes the plural.** I personally think that this example with HelloWorlds (although correct) is rather confusing for newcomers.

- HelloWorld (controller, model and view) (singular) will usually lead to a view where you view or edit a single record.
- HelloWorld**s** will lead to a view where you can view multiple records and perform some operations on them.

On the other hand, I don't think there are a lot of good tutorials, expect that you can look at components included in Joomla (as com_contacts, com_banners, etc).

Also check the documentation regarding [Joomla! Naming Conventions](http://docs.joomla.org/File_Structure_and_Naming_Conventions)

Also I would recommend the book [Joomla! Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013278081X) from Mark Dexter and Louis Landry. They explain in more details how everything fits together.

Comment: Thank you :) One more question - 's' is some thing that have system treatment? I mean: adding of 's' treated by Joomla engine somewhere or only by my code? Its mean: if I will put instead 's' for example 'n' and adopt all the code of HelloWorld component to this change, will it damage functionality some where? For example in class name: HelloWorldViewHelloWorld part 'View' have system treatment, but 'HelloWorld' not. I can change 'HelloWorld' in class name and adopt my component to the change, but I can not change the 'View' part of the class name. So is 's' have some system treatment? Thanx

Comment: The s (for plural) is a Joomla! naming  convention (as well as many other things). So replcing s with n will break your component, as Joomla expects to find a class with "s". Of course, you can override this, but this is another story. HelloWorld is the component name, but you can call it just Hello or anything else - hope this is clear.